# Member of MongoDB replica set cpu load high after other member restarted？

Tags: mongodb

`db version v3.2.10
git version: 79d9b3ab5ce20f51c272b4411202710a082d0317
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
allocator: tcmalloc
modules: none
build environment:
    distmod: rhel62
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64`

The cluster have 1 primary (shorted as p1) and 2 secondary nodes(s2 and s3).
All clients use `secondaryPreferred`

Before the restart, s2 and s3 have same load, same traffic, same qps.

For backup purpose, I stopped the s3, backuped the data and then started. After that, the s2's cpu load went higher, 200% of the s3. And at the same time, s2 and s3 have same traffic, same qps, same connections. Just cpu load became wired.

Restart s2 solve the problem, but I want to know WHY? any bug? or feature?

Comment: what's the readPreference set?

Comment: secondaryPrefered

Comment: you may need to check mongostat and/or profiler when there was load on s2.